# Testing website with a low CPU ghz

Tags: testing

Is there a way to simulate (maybe online) the rendering of a page with a low-end pc?

Actually I am testing it with an i7, but I guess not everyone got a quad-core.

(ps. without downclocking my pc)

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want very poor performances, use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). It's very usefull for this kind of tests

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization might be the best way to test this. You can get [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) for free to try it out.